# Mysql service not starting Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, mysql

Every time I try to start mysql with `sudo service mysql restart` it returns

```
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error
code. See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Does anyone have any ideas of how this is being caused?

This is what came up after `systemctl status mysql.service`

```
Jul 04 15:49:46 sandbox systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
Jul 04 15:49:46 sandbox mysqld[19504]: 2016-07-04T19:49:46.823245Z 0 [Warning] Changed limits: max_open_files: 1024 (requested 5000)
Jul 04 15:49:46 sandbox mysqld[19504]: 2016-07-04T19:49:46.823275Z 0 [Warning] Changed limits: table_open_cache: 431 (requested 2000)
Jul 04 15:49:46 sandbox mysqld[19504]: 2016-07-04T19:49:46.955617Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server opti
Jul 04 15:49:46 sandbox mysqld[19504]: 2016-07-04T19:49:46.955943Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.7.12-0ubuntu1.1-log) starting as process 19504 ...
Jul 04 15:49:46 sandbox mysqld[19504]: 2016-07-04T19:49:46.956626Z 0 [ERROR] COLLATION 'utf8_unicode_ci' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'latin1'
Jul 04 15:49:46 sandbox mysqld[19504]: 2016-07-04T19:49:46.956656Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting
Jul 04 15:49:46 sandbox mysqld[19504]: 2016-07-04T19:49:46.956682Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
Jul 04 15:49:46 sandbox systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
```

Comment: And what is the output of `systemctl status mysql.service` and `journalctl -xe` short after you tried to restart the mysql service? Lets say the last 20 lines.

Comment: Then best write an own answer so you can accept this in two days and thus closing this question as answered :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mysqld.conf file had `collation-set-server = utf8` when it should have been `character-set-server = utf8`